# GeoJson data not working while add KML coordinates?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson

I tried to upload GeoJson data to MapBox but map load empty.

Below is my GeoJson Format Data :
Not Working:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "",
    "properties": {
        "dma": "514",
        "name": "Buffalo, NY"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                -77.06276,38.97872,0.0 -77.02561,38.98378,0.0 -77.00141,38.96493,0.0 -76.99288,38.95822,0.0 -76.98587,38.95274,0.0 -76.97027,38.94054,0.0 -76.96349,38.93524,0.0 -76.94152,38.91827,0.0 -76.93131,38.91004,0.0 -76.92472,38.90488,0.0 -76.91876,38.90021,0.0 -76.9135,38.89608,0.0 -76.91374,38.88947,0.0 -76.91915,38.88526,0.0 -76.92483,38.88081,0.0 -76.93487,38.873,0.0 -76.94078,38.8684,0.0 -76.94899,38.862,0.0 -76.95488,38.85742,0.0 -76.96578,38.84892,0.0 -76.97328,38.84307,0.0 -76.98527,38.83371,0.0 -76.99502,38.8261,0.0 -77.03706,38.79317,0.0 -77.03901,38.79164,0.0 -77.04087,38.82234,0.0 -77.03865,38.83161,0.0 -77.04534,38.83859,0.0 -77.04315,38.83995,0.0 -77.03285,38.84557,0.0 -77.03248,38.85301,0.0 -77.03495,38.85896,0.0 -77.0398,38.8632,0.0 -77.03841,38.86401,0.0 -77.04047,38.87119,0.0 -77.04655,38.87316,0.0 -77.05164,38.87508,0.0 -77.05618,38.8804,0.0 -77.06283,38.88678,0.0 -77.06611,38.8951,0.0 -77.06992,38.90084,0.0 -77.07827,38.90237,0.0 -77.0783,38.90237,0.0 -77.08627,38.90347,0.0 -77.09322,38.90577,0.0 -77.0991,38.90994,0.0 -77.10362,38.91472,0.0 -77.10668,38.9196,0.0 -77.11132,38.92367,0.0 -77.11541,38.92765,0.0 -77.11894,38.93318,0.0 -77.11976,38.93434,0.0 -77.11975,38.93435,0.0 -77.09124,38.95647,0.0
            ]
        ]

    }
  }
]}
```

How to solve the abouve issues.
I can't understand what is the porblem is going on the abouve GeoJson data. Please any one help me to solve the issues.

Other wise how i can upload kml polygon data coordinates to GeoJson data format.

Comment: aren't coordinates suppose to be an Array or Arrays?

Comment: I would like to add coordinates without array.

Comment: Please help me to solve this.

Comment: GeoJson structure expects it to be array of arrays... try it like that if it works. or make a fiddle of it.

Comment: You have 0.0s(z-axis) included without commas before the next number. Those should be stripped out.

Comment: can you please share some example ?